# why javascript contains property is not working in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript

Why javascript contains property  is  not working  in chrome browser?
  I have tried that Contains Property in javascript.It is working fine in Mozila Firefox Browser. But It is not working in Chrome browser.How to fix this?

**Link:** http://www.codingslover.com/2014/11/why-javascript-contains-property-is-not.html

```
var ClearFilterValue='family Schools';
if(ClearFilterValue.contains("family")== true) {
      alert('Success');
}
```

Comment: What version of Chrome? Works fine here

Comment: first, it's working perfectly fine for me in Chrome. second, there's no reason to use `== true`...

Comment: Got an error in Chrome _version 30.0.1599.101 m_ `Uncaught TypeError: Object family Schools has no method 'contains'`

Comment: @palaѕн and @ Elangovan: what version of Chrome are you using? I'm on 30.0.1599.101

Comment: Seems likes contains(); is not supported in Chrome. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Apparently Stack Overflow makes its own implementation of `contains`. (type `String.prototype.contains` into the console here)

Comment: @Doorknob Heh, that'll be why it worked for me too. Good spot!

Comment: you can use indexOf() instead.. like:                         <script type="text/javascript">
 
var ClearFilterValue='family Schools';
if(ClearFilterValue.indexOf("family")!= -1) {
      alert('Success');
}
</script>

Comment: @t.niese No, it's not supported in any Chrome.

Comment: @Doorknob ok yes, my fault. I had in mind that it was added in Chrome 30, and while checking in the console I forgot that i had turned on experimental javascript.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**[indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf)** returns the position of the string. If not found, it will **return -1**:

```
var ClearFilterValue = 'family Schools';
alert(ClearFilterValue.indexOf("family") != -1);
```

Comment: thanks :) Working fine:) I have tried that like that also. 
var n=str.indexOf("family");  
if(n >= 0) {
 alert(success);
}

Answer (score 13):

[`contains` is not supported in Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains), but you could use a polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.contains) {
    String.prototype.contains = function(s) {
        return this.indexOf(s) > -1
    }
}
'potato'.contains('tat') // true
'potato'.contains('tot') // false
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually `String.contains` is not supported in Chrome as per the [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

Here's the way to resolve the issue:

**Polyfill**

You can easily polyfill this method :

```
if (!('contains' in String.prototype)) String.prototype.contains = function (str, startIndex) {
    return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
};

var ClearFilterValue = 'family Schools';
if (ClearFilterValue.contains("family") == true) {
    alert('Success');
}
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/29FcV/)

Answer (score 4):

> You must understand why **contains** is not working. Actually there
>   are two methods **contains** and **includes** and both have different
>   usage.

**contains :**

> The contains() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether a
>   node is a descendant of a specified node.
>
> A descendant can be a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on.

```
var span = document.getElementById("mySPAN");
var div = document.getElementById("myDIV").contains(span);
```

> The result of div will be:

```
true
```

please find [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/fegq8pty/)

**includes :**

> Check if a string includes with "world":

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.includes("world");
```

> The result of n will be:

```
true
```

> Definition and Usage
>
> The includes() method determines whether a string contains the
>   characters of a specified string.
>
> This method returns true if the string contains the characters, and
>     false if not.
>
> Note: The includes() method is case sensitive.

Please find [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/ej7uwzcj/)

> And finally ofcourse you can also use indexOf method to achive same
>   output

```
var ClearFilterValue = 'family Schools';
alert(ClearFilterValue.indexOf("family") != -1);
```

Hope this make sense

Answer (score 1):

Use your own contains method and override firefox's contains() method. Because this method is widely used I mean -> (`indexof`).

```
String.prototype.contains = function(str) { return this.indexOf(str) != -1; };
```

Comment: *Never* override prototype methods of objects you don't own. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using indexOf

```
var ClearFilterValue = 'family Schools';
if(ClearFilterValue.indexOf("family") !== -1) {
      alert('Success');
}
```

Also not sure if you should be making a polyfill as pretty much no browser seems to support it anyways https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

None of IE's support it, Chrome apparently starting at 30, FF starting at 19, and i doubt mobile browsers support it either