# jQuery add URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a jquery multiple drag and drop file uploader using dropzone.js.

I have added the following code to the dropzone code

```
  this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
      alert("&success=yes");

  });
```

So when the queue has completed it sends an alert at the moment however I want to change it so it so that using jquery it adds this as a parameter to the URL.

Any ideas how to do this using jquery?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to add the parameter to the current page's URL and reload the page with the URL plus the parameter. Is this the real question?

Comment: This is jQuery specific. The duplicate question is javascript specific, and has no jquery tag.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will do the job...

```
this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
      var url = document.location.href+"&success=yes";
      document.location = url;
  });
```

Option two (in case you already have one parameter)

```
this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
    if(document.location.href.contains('?')) {
        var url = document.location.href+"&success=yes";
    }else{
        var url = document.location.href+"?success=yes";
    }
      document.location = url;
  });
```

Comment: ...unless there's no `?` in the URL.

Comment: that's a quick fix... give a sec

Comment: there you go.... It will check if you have a paremeter in your url first and then it will add the right parameter

Comment: I would recommend to use an standard URI/URL manipulation library for this, e.g. http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.location.href.contains is not a function

Comment: @user2924019 [not all browsers support String.prototype.contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589465/why-javascript-contains-property-is-not-working-in-chrome-browser). Try replacing `.contains('?')` with `.indexOf('?') != -1`.

Comment: @LeoJavier, looks like [MDN recommends `.includes` instead of `.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) anyhow.

Comment: The question asks for jQuery solution, this uses no jQuery.